# Calculate the lagged differences between consecutive dates in vectors

Tags: r, date, tidyverse

The sample dataset is given as below:

```
v = data.frame(group = c(1,1,2,3,3),date = as.Date(c('01-01-2000','01-01-2001','01-05-2000','02-07-2000','01-01-2008'), "%d-%m-%Y"))
  
v%>% group_by(group ) %>% mutate(difference_day = ifelse(n() == 2, 
                                                         c(0,diff(date )),
                                                         difftime(date ,as.Date('31-12-2021', "%d-%m-%Y"),units='days')))
```

My desirable result is :

| group | difference_day |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 365 |
| 2 | 7915 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 2740 |

In the above code, if the length of groups is equal to one, then the days_difference will be
`difftime(date ,as.Date('31-12-2021', "%d-%m-%Y"),units='days'))`.

However,
the output of the code was:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
# Groups:   group [3]
  group date       difference_day
  <dbl> <date>              <dbl>
1     1 2000-01-01              0
2     1 2001-01-01              0
3     2 2000-05-01          -7914
4     3 2000-07-02              0
5     3 2008-01-01              0
```

which was very strange.
Please give me some suggestions, thank you!

Comment: `v %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(d = c(0, diff(date)))` makes more sense to me, but I can't understand where your expectation of `7915` comes from.

Comment: I calculated by hand...

Comment: '2021-12-31'-'2000-05-01'=7915

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to replace either the first vector or the second vector, use `if` instead of `if_else`. (That is, your conditional is external to the vectors, not an element-by-element conditional, where `if_else` would be more appropriate.)

```r
v %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(d = if (n() == 2L) diff(c(date[1], date)) else difftime(as.Date("2021-12-31"), date, units = "days")) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 5 × 3
#   group date       d        
#   <dbl> <date>     <drtn>   
# 1     1 2000-01-01    0 days
# 2     1 2001-01-01  366 days
# 3     2 2000-05-01 7914 days
# 4     3 2000-07-02    0 days
# 5     3 2008-01-01 2739 days
```

There are some differences of +/- 1 from your expected output, not sure if that was a typo or some other intent outside of a traditional `diff`.

The return from both `diff` and `difftime` here are class `"difftime"`, which *prints* naturally with `". days"`; they are still number-enough that math  or such still works on them. If you prefer not, just wrap with `as.integer(.)` or `as.numeric(.)`.

Comment: Actually, I would say `mutate(Diff = date- lag(date))` is the best solution if it can also handle the cases when `n() ==1`. Would you mind providing one more way to solve through `lag`...? Since I get stuck in it...

Comment: If you really need it, then replace `diff(c(date[1], date))` with `date - lag(date, default=date[1])`

Comment: I want to ask one more thing: why my code cannot work? Is it because of `ifelse`? `ifelse` cannot be applied to the case-'conditional is external to the vectors'? Thank you

Comment: `ifelse`/`if_else` expects three vectors, all equal length: the conditional, the yes/true vector, and the no/false vector. In your case, your conditional vector is length-1, so it will only evaluate length-1 of all of the other vector-like things. In `ifelse`, the cond is evaluated one-by-one, perhaps grabbing some elements from the "yes" vector and some elements from the "no" vectors. You need all of one or all of the other, so it is not a vectorized operation.

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind recommending a book that is related to vectorized operation in r? I am so unfamiliar with this type of function...

Comment: So can I say that `ifelse` bypasses `group_by`?

Comment: Book? Hmmm ... Hadley's [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Introduction.html) is generally quite good, I'd start there. Comparing `ifelse` and `group_by` is not usable, they do completely different things (and orthogonally at that).